# Local Installation of Wikipedia Search API

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am currently using the Wikipedia [search API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=xxxxxxxxxxxxx) heavily on R&D. And given that it's got usage limits, I was wondering if it is possible to download the exact search functionality Wikipedia is using?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can [download all Wikimedia projects](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/), [import them in your instance](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Tools_for_importing) and [install all extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Extensions_used_on_Wikimedia) (or at least the parsing ones) including [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch).

However, you are quite unlikely to run into search API limits: just make sure to [set a user-agent](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) so that you can be contacted and avoid doing stupid things (like running 1000 threads in parallel), you'll be fine. Wikimedia Foundation never blocks anyone unless the cluster gets into trouble.